# Chromium Embedded Framework favicon

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, chromium, favicon, chromium-embedded

How to get favicon website with Chromium Embedded Framework? I could look at the source code and get the url of the icon, but some sites, like Facebook, do not use a standard procedure to add a favicon, then, how do I get the favicon? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rules for the favicon are all explained on the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) page.

> The standards use a link element with a rel attribute in the `<head>` section of the document to specify the file format, file name and a location can be specified for any Web site directory.

You need to look, inside the `<head>` element, for `link` elements of this form:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://example.com/myicon.ico" />
```

or

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon"
    href="http://example.com/image.ico" />
```

If you don't find such links, then use the fall back of looking for `favicon.ico` at the root directory.

---

I'm not certain why you think that Facebook don't follow the standard. I just looked at an FB page which contained this:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" 
    href="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/yP/r/Ivn-CVe5TGK.ico" />
```

It's not possible for websites to use some other mechanism to get favicons to browsers. The browsers follow the well-defined rules for getting favicons. If a website did something different, the browser would not find the favicon.

Comment: Thank you, but there is a specific function in the Chromium Embedded Framework that allows this or do I have to look in the source code?

Comment: You can just read it out of the DOM. Should be trivial to do that. Don't attempt to parse the raw HTML!! If there is a function to extract it, a search of the source code will find it.

Comment: Thanks, however in the source code there is no trace of the favicon, I'll find another way.

Answer (score 3):

From this [blog entry](http://pascaliburnus.seanbdurkin.id.au/index.php?/archives/4-Favicons!-How-to-implement-them..html), the best practice for cross-browser supported favicons is to include

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="http://www.example.com/image.ico"> <!-- For good browsers. -->
<link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="http://www.example.com/image.ico"/> <!-- For Internet Explorer-->
```

The first link is for real browsers and the second is for ie rubbish. On some websites you will see `type="image/x-icon"` in the `link` tag. There was a time when this was the correct implementation, but `image/x-icon` has now been superceded by `image/vnd.microsoft.icon` which is now part of the IANA standard for MIME types.

By the way, older versions of ie just looked for a file name `/favicon.ico` which was hard-coded. If you wanted to be ultra safe, you should name your favicon as `favicon.ico`. Of course that does not help you if your domain hosts multiple web-sites for different purposes.

Note: If you don't need to support favicons for IE, then you are then free to use png, gif and jpg formats for your favicon, as indicated below...

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://www.example.com/image.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="http://www.example.com/image.gif">
<link rel="icon" type="image/jpeg" href="http://www.example.com/image.jpg">
```

Answer (score 1):

CEF1 has a callback named `OnFaviconURLChange` that's called whenever the favicon URL for a page changes.  CEF3 doesn't support this callback yet, according to [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/issues/detail?id=964) in the CEF issue tracker.

Comment: Is there a workaround for how to get favicons in CEF3?

Comment: `OnFaviconURLChange` is now available in CEF3.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a client handler and at least CefDisplayHandler. This class have the OnFaviconURLChange (not sure in what version did appear, but for sure is present in branch 2357 and later).
C++ prototype is:

```
void OnFaviconURLChange(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser, 
  const std::vector<CefString>& icon_urls);
```

icon_urls usually contains a single entry (if any), which is the URL of the favicon.
Consider also checking the favicon URL for its security, I passed the URL to a HTMLayout application only to discover that was on a self-signed https:// resource and all sorts of wininet security error (InternetErrorDlg for example) started throwing all the place.